How does the polarity of the magnet changes when flipped upside down? What happens to the direction of magnetic domains and magnetic line of force?
Imagine you have two flat bar magnet with dimensions as $L \times B \times H = 100 \times 50 \times 5$ each. The $B \times H$ side of magnet 1 is facing the $B \times H$ side of the magnet 2. And let's say they both have same poles facing each other (N-N). Obviously they will repel each other. But when I flip magnet 2 upside down while the same two faces $B \times H$ are facing each other and same poles (N-N), however, now it attracts can you explain what happens there in terms of direction of magnetic domain within the magnet and magnetic lines of forces.

It is not clear what you mean at the end (when you write they are facing each other with "same poles (N-N), however, now it attracts". Why do you think it attracts? What situation you are referring to?)

@Yash, I don't think this situation is actually possible. North to north will always repel.

I don't know about magnetic domains within the material, but as for the lines of force, does this help?


If I was a better artist, I would have done a better job rendering the lines between the two "N" poles in the upper diagram to show them smushed up real tight against each other.
